# T-SQL DateTime to Date Conversion - Tolerance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, date-conversion

We are attempting to strip the time off a DateTime variable:

```
DECLARE @Date DateTime 

SET @Date = '01Jan2013 23:59:59.998'
PRINT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Date ))

SET @Date = '01Jan2013 23:59:59.999'
PRINT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Date ))
```

**Result:**

> Jan  1 2013 12:00AM
>   Jan  2 2013 12:00AM

Why does `01Jan2013 23:59:59.999` come back as **2nd Jan** rather than 1st Jan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there's no .999 and .998 fraction of a second in datetime type. You only have .990, .993 and .997.

So .998 is rounded down to .997, while .999 is rounded up.
Read more about the type.